# Meteor - Cancelling a Server Method from the Client

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm performing a database count through a server method. Users can select how they want the count to be performed and then invoke the method.

My problem is that the count can take some time and a user might change their mind while the method is running and request a different count. Is there any way for me to cancel the invoked method and run a new count?

I've thought this.unblock() might work; it will allow a new method to be run, but it won't cancel the old method. I've also considered pre-counting and then just using a lookup, but there are too many selector combinations.

Here's my code, it's fairly simple:

```
//Server
Meteor.methods({
    getFilterCount: function(oFilterSelector) {
        return clMaBldgs.find(oFilterSelector, {}).count();
    }
});

//Client
Meteor.call('getFilterCount', oFilterSelector, function (error, result) {
    //do some stuff
});
```

Comment: Did you find out? Would like to know, too. Any way to display a list of running calls?

Comment: Sadly, no. However, I did find this tip in the mongo documentation. Haven't tried it yet. It might work for canceling db ops:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/

Comment: A little late to the game here but it seems like `unblock` is still the recommended way to go; referencing the [current Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#methods-vs-rest), 3rd paragraph down.

Comment: @chazsolo, unblock definitely allows you to run a new function, the problem is the old function might still be running. It'd be nice to kill old processes if you know you don't need them anymore.

Comment: @Adam agreed, just saying that's all I was able to find, other than the `db.killOp` reference in Mongo you found. Perhaps it's something on MDG's roadmap?

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling an already-made method call to server from client is not possible.

But if your method are called multiple times in a short interval, and you only care about the last call's result. You could use [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) to delay execution for some times. This will help reduce unnecessary calls to server.

Answer (score 0):

More of a work around, but if you had a reactive variable (could be an entry in the DB) that is a status of the method, and in the method itself, you check for that flag every chance you get for the status.

```
{
    _id: "some id for the method", running: true
}
```

Pseudocode for method

```
Meteor.methods({
    method: (_id) => {
        status = getStatusForId(_id);
        while(status) {
            status = getStatusForId(_id);
        }
    }
});
```

Then to stop it, you just update that flag to be false and the method will stop as soon as it can.