# Meteor method loop break

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a long running taks if i click a method and on the server-side
a loop iterates through a collection. Actually the collection can be long and i have a second button which should break the first method-call and therefore the for-loop.

```
Meteor.methods({
    first(){
    let data = Data.find({}).fetch();
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                let d = `${data[i].t}`;
                mqttClient.publish("test", d);
                Meteor._sleepForMs(data[i].duration*1000);
            }
    },
cancelFirst(){ ??//process.exit(); }
```

Restarting the Meteor app is not a good choice with `process.extit()`

How can i handle this ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944316/meteor-cancelling-a-server-method-from-the-client

Answer (score 0):

I created a working Meteor 1.4 project that accomplishes what you want. The not so straightforward part is the this.unblock() inside the starLoop method.

https://github.com/Bizow/meteor-method-loop-break

Comment: it wont work following scenario im using meteor 1.4 the outer while loop also works if the canRun Property is set top false